# Replace name and return an object

Tags: object

We need to keep track of the school students, but the data we currently have combines the students first and last names into a single name. You have been asked to separate the names to make the data easier to work with.

The makeStudentList function takes an object with a name property whose value will be a string consisting of a first name and a last name, separated by a space. The function should return an object.

The function should remove the name property, replace it with firstName and lastName properties, as shown in the examples below.

Examples:

makeStudentList({ name: "Hannah Fry", age: 4 })
// should return { firstName: "Hannah", lastName: "Fry", age: 4 }

makeGuestList({ name: "Paul Erdős", age: 6 })
// should return { firstName: "Paul", lastName: "Erdős", age: 6 }

Comment: Is this an assignment question? :) Maybe you can post something you've tried and then we can discuss the solution so you're able to understand be able to solve it yourself?

Comment: it's a kata that I am trying to solve , I have tried :function makeStudentList(person) { 
let name= student.name.split(' ');

return {"firstName": name[0], "lastName" :name[1]};
}.     it is always passing one part of splicing and replacing the name but it is showing one error :All other properties on the object are unchanged
Errors. I have tried so many things .

Comment: I see. Could you post the link to the kata here? Maybe I can give it a try as well. Also, I have posted my answer.

Comment: Also, to explain why it might not be working, "The function should remove the name property, replace it with firstName and lastName properties" which means you need to modify the actual object, if I understand it correctly. So, in your case when you return a new object, the test fails, since it's a new object, all the properties are unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function makeStudentList(student) {
    const [firstName, lastName] = student.name.split(" ");
  delete student.name;
  student.firstName = firstName;
  student.lastName = lastName;
  return student;
} // should return { firstName: "Hannah", lastName: "Fry", age: 4 }

let response = makeStudentList({ name: "Hannah Fry", age: 4 });

const p = document.querySelector('p');
p.append(JSON.stringify(response));
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: Perfect. If it was useful, maybe you could vote the solution as the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def makeStudentList(name,age):
    Name=name.split(" ")
    return {"FirstName":Name[0],"lastName":Name[1],"Age":age}
    
        
makeStudentList("Hannah Fry",4)
```

Here you go, lemme know if you need any sort of explanation, cheers:)

Comment: i have tried it befire, it is passing one part of splicing and replacing the name but also showing one Error:All other properties on the object are unchanged.?